# How to ensure a cfobject variable is local to a function?

Tags: coldfusion

Assuming the following code in a regular .cfm file, *not* a CFC:

> `<cffunction name="myFunction">
>     <cfobject type="java" action="create" class="path.to.my.java.class" name="myJavaVariable">
>   </cffunction>`

What is going to be the scope of the created object? I'm getting the feeling it's *not* limited to the function scope. If so, how to make it local? Would the following work?

> `<cfset var myJavaVariable = "">
>   <cfobject ... name="myJavaVariable">`

EDIT:
I forgot to say I was under Coldfusion MX 7, as it does prevent some useful solutions found on the web from working.

I did find a workaround where one creates a fake local scope (`<cfset var local = StructNew()>`). It does work well even for such tags since you can put the return variable as `local.someVar`.

Comment: Yes, pre-varring will work, as should `name="local.mJavaVariable"` in newer versions of CFML - you can of course verify it's going into local scope with `<cfdump var=#local# />`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd question why you're using `<cfobject>` at all, rather than the more obvious simple assignment:

```
var myJavaVariable = createObject("java", "path.to.my.java.class");
```

Isn't that more natural code anyhow?

Comment: Chalk it up to ignorance, unless of course this form is unavailable under CFMX7? I'll try to check at work tomorrow.

Comment: It's been there since at least CF 4.5. But no worries, we all learn stuff every day.